# How can I do set NULL into the table in Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

I have some table `store_section`(`id`,`parent_id`,`label`), I want to change some row, set parent_id=null.

I trying to:

```
$record = $table->getTable()->find( $id );
$record->parent_id = null;
$record->save();
```

But this isn't work. How can I do set NULL into the table in Doctrine, in example above, parent_id becomes =0 (not =NULL)?

Thnx for the responses!

Comment: Does your table definition specify 0 as the default value for `parent_id`?

Comment: No, value by default = null NULL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would try one of the following:

1:

```
$record = $table->getTable()->find( $id );
$record->parent_id = new Doctrine_Null();
$record->save();
```

2:

```
$record = $table->getTable()->find( $id );
$record->parent_id = "NULL";
$record->save();
```

I have not tested these, but I do recall having a similar issue prior, just cannot recall how I solved it.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Ftr, "NULL" !== NULL. Your 2nd solution actually inserts the string NULL.

Answer (score 4):

You can use method set('u.name', 'NULL')
For example:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()->update('User u')->set('u.name', 'NULL')->where('u.id = ?',$id);
```

Answer (score 3):

`Doctrine_Null` only has two methods, and the one that seems to relate is the `__toString` method. So in order to activate the magic method you need to cast as a string:

```
$record = $table->getTable()->find( $id );
$record->parent_id = (string) new Doctrine_Null;
$record->save();
```

But honestly there is no reason, as `Doctrine_Null` just abstracts an empty string `''`. I can only assume that it only works in this scenario because parent_id is not enforcing a `NULL` attribute.

Setting a value of 'NULL' **appears** to work but is actually a string and not NULL.

```
'NULL' !== null
```

Give it a shot, if you insert 'NULL' into one row, and another row is a "natural NULL", and you pull both rows out of the table and do a `var_dump(serialize())` on each, you will see one is a natural null and other is actually a string.

If you want to maintain consistency and enforce natural nulls, use this instead:

```
$record = $table->getTable()->find( $id );
$record->parent_id = new Doctrine_Expression('NULL');
$record->save();
```

Comment: Where all the solutions above fails in Doctrine 1.2, `new Doctrine_Expression('NULL')` seems to works pretty well actually. Thanks you for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, when the field is a relation. I have complished this task with:

```
$record->Parent = null;
$record->save();
```

Above Parent is the relation name.

Answer (score 0):

In Doctrine2 Using the query builder, you can also directly update the value in the db.

```
    $qb = // $this->connection->createQueryBuilder(); or $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->update('store_section', 's')
        ->set('s.parent_id', ':parent_id')
        ->andWhere('s.id', ':id'));
    $qb->setParameter('parent_id', null);
    $qb->setParameter('id', $id);
    $qb->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$record->setParentId(null);
$record->save();
```

Comment: You should better update your answer instead of posting a new one.